# Translations not loaded on odoo 10 enterprise

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

I have the following qweb template:

INVOICE

```
    <div class="col-xs-12" style="font-family: Calibri Bold">
    </div>
    <br></br>
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <div class="col-xs-5" style="height: 130px; border: 2px solid; padding: 10px 10px;font-family: Calibri">
            <div t-field="company.name"/>
            <div t-field="company.street"/>
            <div t-field="company.street2"/>
            <div>VAT :<span style="color:white">.</span><span t-field="company.vat"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-offset-7 text-center" style="height: 130px; border: 2px solid; padding: 10px 10px;font-family: Calibri">
            <address t-field="o.partner_id" 
                    t-field-options='{"widget": "contact", "fields": ["address", "name"], "no_marker": true}' />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12" style=" height: 68px; margin-top:20px; margin-bottom: 25px;">
        <div class="col-xs-5" style="border: 2px solid; padding: 10px 10px; margin-bottom: 25px; font-family: Calibri">
            <div style="max-height:20px;">
            <h2 t-if="o.number" style="font-size:inherit;">
                Invoice Number :<span style="color:white">.</span>
                <span t-field="o.number"/>
            </h2>
            </div>
            <div t-if="o.date_invoice">
                Invoice Date :<span style="color:white">.</span>
                <span t-field="o.date_invoice"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-offset-7 text-center col-xs-5" style="border: 2px solid; margin-top: -69px; margin-bottom: 25px; padding: 10px 10px;font-family: Calibri">
            <div t-if="o.partner_id.vat">
                VAT Number :<span style="color:white">.</span>
                <span t-field="o.company_id.vat"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br></br>
    <div class="col-xs-12" style="font-family: Calibri Bold">
    </div>
<div class="col-xs-12">
    <table class="table table-condensed">
        <thead>
            <tr style="border: 2px solid; border-left: 2px solid; border-right: 2px solid; font-family: Calibri Bold;">
                <th style="border: 2px solid;">Description</th>
                <th style="border: 2px solid;" class="text-center">Quantity</th>
                <th style="border: 2px solid;" class="text-center">Unit Price</th>
                <th style="border: 2px solid;" class="text-center">Discount</th>
                <th style="border: 2px solid;" class="text-center">Amount</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody style="border: 2px solid;font-family: Calibri" class="invoice_tbody">
            <tr t-foreach="o.invoice_line_ids" t-as="l">
                <td style="border-left: 2px solid;">
                    <span t-field="l.name"/>
                </td>
                <td style="border-left: 2px solid;" class="text-center">
                    <span t-field="l.quantity"/>
                </td>
                <td class="text-center" style="border-left: 2px solid;">
                    <span t-field="l.price_unit"/>
                    <span t-field="l.uom_id"  groups="product.group_uom"/>
                </td>
                <td class="text-center" style="border-left: 2px solid;">
                </td>
                <td class="text-center" style="border-left: 2px solid; border-right: 2px solid">
                    <span t-field="l.price_subtotal" 
                        t-field-options='{"widget": "monetary", "display_currency": "o.currency_id"}'/>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
<div>
    <div class="col-xs-13" t-if="o.payment_term_id">
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            <table class="table table-condensed">
                <thead>
                    <tr style="font-family: Calibri Bold;">
                        <th>Payment Terms</th>
                        <th>Date</th>
                        <th class="text-right">Amount</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr style="font-family: Calibri">
                        <td><span t-field="o.payment_term_id"/></td>
                        <td>
                            <span t-field="o.date_due"/>
                        </td>
                        <td class="text-right">
                            <span t-field="o.discount_price"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-offset-7">
    <table class="table table-condensed">
        <tr style="border: 2px solid;font-family: Calibri">
            <td class="text-right" style="border: 2px solid; border-left: 2px solid; border-right: 2px solid;"><span>Subtotal</span></td>
            <td class="text-right" style="border: 2px solid; border-left: 2px solid; border-right: 2px solid;">
                <span t-field="o.amount_untaxed" t-field-options='{"widget": "monetary", "display_currency": "o.currency_id"}'/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="font-family: Calibri">
            <td class="text-right" style="border: 2px solid; border-left: 2px solid; border-right: 2px solid;"><span>Discount</span></td>
            <td class="text-right" style="border: 2px solid; border-left: 2px solid; border-right: 2px solid;">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="font-family: Calibri">
            <td class="text-right" style="border: 2px solid; border-left: 2px solid; border-right: 2px solid;"><span>VAT</span></td>
            <td class="text-right" style="border: 2px solid; border-left: 2px solid; border-right: 2px solid;">
                <span t-field="o.amount_tax" t-field-options='{"widget": "monetary", "display_currency": "o.currency_id"}'/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="font-family: Calibri">
            <td class="text-right" style="border: 2px solid; border-left: 2px solid; border-right: 2px solid;"><span>Amount</span></td>
            <td class="text-right" style="border: 2px solid; border-left: 2px solid; border-right: 2px solid;">
                 <span t-field="o.amount_total" t-field-options='{"widget": "monetary", "display_currency": "o.currency_id"}'/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="font-family: Calibri">
            <td class="text-right" style="border: 0px solid; border-left: 0px solid; border-right: 0px solid; font-family: Calibri Bold;"></td>
            <td class="text-right" style="border: 0px solid; border-left: 0px solid; border-right: 0px solid; font-family: Calibri Bold;"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="font-family: Calibri">
            <td class="text-right" style="border: 4px solid; border-left: 4px solid; border-right: 4px solid; font-family: Calibri Bold;"><span>Total</span></td>
            <td class="text-right" style="border: 4px solid; border-left: 4px solid; border-right: 4px solid; font-family: Calibri Bold;">
                 <span t-field="o.amount_total" t-field-options='{"widget": "monetary", "display_currency": "o.currency_id"}'/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>

</div>

</div>
<div class="footer" style="border-top:2px solid">
    <div class="col-xs-12 text-center">
        <table class="col-xs-12 text-center">
            <tr style="height: 34px;font-family: Calibri">
                <td>


                </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

I also have set up some translations for the Dutch language by creating the file `my_module/i18n/nl.po` The contents of the file are:

```
#. module: custom
#: view:website:account.report_invoice_document
msgid "Telephone"
msgstr "Telefoon"

#. module: custom
#: view:website:account.report_invoice_document
msgid "Invoice Number"
msgstr "Factuurnummer"

#. module: custom
#: view:website:account.report_invoice_document
msgid "Invoice Date :"
msgstr "Factuurdatum : "

#. module: custom
#: view:website:account.report_invoice_document
msgid "INVOICE"
msgstr "FACTUUR"

#. module: custom
#: view:website:account.report_invoice_document
msgid "Invoice Number"
msgstr "Factuur nummer"

#. module: custom
#: view:website:account.report_invoice_document
msgid "VAT"
msgstr "BTW"

#. module: custom
#: view:website:account.report_invoice_document
msgid "Discount"
msgstr "Korting"

#. module: custom
#: view:website:account.report_invoice_document
msgid "Refund"
msgstr "Creditnota"
```

While I can see from the logs that this file is loaded and the translations are loaded, they do not appear on the report.

When I go to Settings -> Translations -> Translated Terms I can see my terms that have been translated correctly. But they do not appear on the report. The report has `attachment_use="False"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to resolve the issue by delving a little deeper in the whole translation functionality, I will outline the process here to resolve the issue for further reference:

I will write the reasons as to why the translations were not being loaded here for further reference:

> 1) First of all, the translations written in the po file must match
>   exactly those in the qweb template. The strings in the qweb template
>   must not contain other tags, for example: 
>                          VAT Number :.
>
> The "VAT Number :" string here could not be translated because of the
>   span element. If you provide a translation for the VAT Number: you
>   have to include the whole span element as well.
>
> 2) Delete already existing translations for your string because they
>   will not be overwritten. (Activate debug mode -> Settings ->
>   Translations -> Translated Terms)
>
> 3) Load the new translations by going to  (Activate debug mode ->
>   Settings -> Translations -> Synchronize Terms)
>
> 4) Optional: If we have a report, make sure that you uncheck the
>   Reload from Attachment, so that the old report does not get loaded
>   when you test.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example from the `website` module. They have this template :

```
<template id="show_sign_in" customize_show="True" inherit_id="website.layout" name="Show Sign In">
    <xpath expr="//ul[@id='top_menu']" position="inside">
        <li class="divider" groups="base.group_public"/>
        <li groups="base.group_public">
            <a t-attf-href="/web/login">
                <b>Sign in</b>
            </a>
        </li>
    </xpath>
</template>
```

This is how it is translated :

```
#. module: website
#: model:ir.ui.view,arch_db:website.show_sign_in
msgid "<b>Sign in</b>"
msgstr "<b>Aanmelden</b>"
```

Good day.